# Exchange 2010 user not receiving mail from another user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have an Outlook 2010 user who can't receive email from another Outlook 2010 user.  They are both in the same mailbox server in the same network.  They can both send and receive email to anyone else in the organization.  One just can't receive from the other.  It's very strange.

Exchange server was recently migrated from 2007 to 2010 but one of the users described is a new hire which was created on the 2010 server.  I have other new hires created on the 2010 server that work fine.

I tried having the user send from OWA and it still doesn't get through.  What else can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the "Blocked Senders" list under their Junk options in Outlook?

Comment: Yes, I even added the sender to the "Safe Senders" list.  No dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the message tracking log. This will tell you what has happened to the message and why it isn't getting delivered. There is also the mail flow troubleshooting tool in Exchange which will help you track down the source of the problem.

Comment: Oh boy, funny story.  The user had a folder for this sender and a rule to put all her messages into that folder.  He didn't even know about it.  Discovered this through the tracking log.  Moral: it sometimes pays to not assume the user knows their Outlook.